# Beautifulsoup select works in Jupyter but not in VS Code

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, beautifulsoup, jupyter-notebook

I build a webcrawler in Python with Request and Beautifulsoup to read informations from a website. First I made a protoype with Jupyter:

```
values = [x.find("div") for x in soup.find_all('td', {'data-alias': "product"})]

for i in range(0, len(values)):
    print(values[i]["data-body"])
```

The result in Jupyter is as expected a "clean" HTML content:

```
<table cellpadding="2" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="w100"><tr><td class="w16"><img src="03.gif" alt="" /></td><td class="nw b">1</td><td class="nw"></td></tr><tr><td class="w16"><img src="00.gif" alt="" /></td><td class="nw b">2</td><td class="nw"></td></tr></table>
```

When I run the same code within VS Code, I get the following error

```
print(values[i]["data-body"])
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
```

I removed the ["data-body"] to check the data.

```
<div class="fl nw" data-body='&lt;table cellpadding="2" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="w100"&gt;&lt;tr&gt;&lt;td class="w16"&gt;&lt;img src="03.gif" alt="" /&gt;&lt;/td&gt;&lt;td class="nw b"&gt;1&lt;/td&gt;&lt;td class="nw"&gt;&lt;/td&gt;&lt;/tr&gt;&lt;tr&gt;&lt;td class="w16"&gt;&lt;img src="00.gif" alt="" /&gt;&lt;/td&gt;&lt;td class="nw b"&gt;2&lt;/td&gt;&lt;td class="nw"&gt;&lt;/td&gt;&lt;/tr&gt;&lt;/table&gt;' data-tooltip-head="Content"></div>
```

The data-body looks like an encoded HTML content. But why is this code working well on Jupyter and leads to an error in VS Code?

Comment: Are you using the same environment that you ran Jupyter under? Or are you using a separate environment in VS Code and thus could have installed a different version of some libraries?

Comment: For VS Code I´m using anaconda with only one environment. Does Jupyter use it´s own environment? How can I check if both use the same environment hat have the same library versions?

Comment: The question is what environment you ran Jupyter under. It doesn't necessarily have a separate environment, it's a question of whether you ran VS Code in the same activated conda environment as you did Jupyter?

Comment: I,m running the .py and .ipynb file in VS code. Both use Python 3.7.6. Both use base environment of anaconda

Comment: Then I would execute the notebook from a clean kernel top to bottom and then export that exact same code out and run it that way. Typically differences occur when migrating out of Jupyter notebooks due to differences in cell execution order compared to executing the file. But otherwise it's hard to know why the difference as you're running under very different environments.